# What are these white sacs on the branch of Lilly Pilly?

Tags: identification

There are many while sacs adhered to the branches of a Lilly Pilly.

[image: white sacs]

Their sizes are between half a cm to one.

Here is the plant itself

[image]

What are these white sacs? I broke one of them and all I can see is some form of liquid.

Comment: Inside of a bubble I found 5mm long jumping insect.
not a spider or a bug but as said INSECT.
A photo can be provided as well as a video.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like white wax scale infestation - you may or may not have noticed ants on the plant as well, coming for the honeydew they produce. As the infestation progresses, you may find the plant develops sooty mould, which is also related to the presence of this pest.

From what I've read, I believe in Australia you have something called 'white oil' which is a treatment for this pest, but most mature plants are able to withstand the presence of this pest. Further information here https://www.searlesgardening.com.au/australian-native-pests-and-diseases

Answer (score 0):

In my case the leaves are not effected just branches and yes it is called Psyllidis. they produce waxy foam LERPS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).